# How can I assign a type to an object without affecting the implicit type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

If I have an interface/type like so:

```
interface ITest {
  abc: string[]
}
```

then I assign it to an object like so:

```
const obj: ITest = {
  abc: ["x", "y", "z"]
}
```

then try to create a type based on the values of the abc property...

`type ABCVal = (typeof obj.abc)[number]`

`ABCVal` becomes simply `string`

**How can I have `ABCVal` be equal to `"x" | "y" | "z"` whilst still restricting the `abc` array to only contain strings?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator and a [`const`-assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) like so:

```
interface ITest {
  abc: string[]
}

const obj =  {
  abc: ["x", "y", "z"]
} as const satisfies ITest;

type ABCVal = (typeof obj.abc)[number]
//   ^? type ABCVal = "x" | "y" | "z"
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyycARggFzI5SgDmA2gLoEC+BBCA9iDsl6QBWyALzFCxMpWQMARAA9ZAGmSyAnstUAvWS1Yksybr1xY4YYFhjBsaTDgDcHMGoAOKAIIAhAMIA1OAAbUWQAChd3Lhh+IQA6KQBKBhAAVwBbUmgWAHps4mQAPQB+IA)